# VS code - integrated terminal - keyboard shortcut to toggle between code and terminal?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Any suggestions how to toggle between code and integrated terminal in VS Code?

In PowerShell ISE for example it's :  <kbd>Ctr+D</kbd> terminal and <kbd>Ctr+I</kbd> code

Can't find anything similar for VS Code.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Comment: `Ctrl+\`` toggles the console, you can set up you're own keybinding as well (`File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts`)

Comment: great Thank you!

Comment: Another thread exists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796887/switch-focus-between-editor-and-integrated-terminal/43012779#43012779     My take: `Ctrl + M` for toggle between VS code frames

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At current, the last post by sqlaide on [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19400) had a great answer (that works). You open up your keybindings.json* file and add the text below between the square brackets. Once complete, you can use Ctrl+` to move focus back and forth between the code and the terminal.

*File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts and click on keybindings.json.

```
{
"key": "ctrl+`",        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
                        "when": "!terminalFocus"},
{
"key": "ctrl+`",        "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
                        "when": "terminalFocus"}
```

Comment: Perhaps one of the new unassigned viewport navigation commands would work for you, such as 'workbench.action.navigateDown' .

Answer (score 0):

elaborating on the previous answer, I would like to share my working configuration to switch between Code and Terminal with or without full-sized Terminal.

NOTE: I tested this on my Mac, running VSCode on an EC2 instance.

#### settings.json

```json
{
  "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.move2Terminal",
      "sequence": [
        "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel",
        "workbench.action.terminal.focus"
      ]
    },
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.move2Code",
      "sequence": [
        "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel",
        "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### keybindings.json

```json
[
  // Switch between Terminal and Code
  {
    "key": "shift+cmd+,",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
    "when": "!terminalFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+cmd+,",
    "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  }
  // Switch to Terminal full-screen and back to Code
  {
    "key": "shift+cmd+.",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
      "command": "multiCommand.move2Terminal"
    },
    "when": "!terminalFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+cmd+.",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
      "command": "multiCommand.move2Code"
    },
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },
]
```