# How to switch between terminals in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, ide, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking to switch between terminals open in visual studio code.

With this ["Switch focus between editor and integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796887/switch-focus-between-editor-and-integrated-terminal-in-visual-studio-code) question I correctly setup the focus, but I would like to switch between terminals, not only from code to terminal.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: i still to this day avoid using the integrated console. hopefully someone could enlight me with a good workflow

Comment: @GottZ I think it's main use for when you are logged in to clusters. How else could you open your files without the integrated console?

Comment: @giannisgonidelis since we are in 2020 now, i agree. the integrated console has evolved beyond xterm.js and is insanely capable now.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

As of Release 1.56.0, there is inbuilt support for switching terminals in VS Code:

> **New keybindings**
>
> The terminal has several new default keybindings this release:
>
> 1. Move to previous terminal - `Ctrl+PageUp (macOS Cmd+Shift+])`
> 2. Move to next terminal - `Ctrl+PageDown (macOS Cmd+shift+[)`
> 3. Focus terminal tabs view - `Ctrl+Shift+\ (macOS Cmd+Shift+\)` - Terminal tabs preview
>
> As always, these default keybindings can be removed or custom
> keybindings can be added via the keybindings system.

Comment: You could add the shortcuts to your answer:

`workbench.action.terminal.focusNext`
`workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious`

and I find even better to remove the `terminalFocus` from the when expression, so you can change terminals without focusing the terminal

Comment: On my international Spanish ISO keyboard, this doesn't seem to work, although if I switch to US Keyboard it does. (Neither works Cmd-AltGr-[ nor Cmd-Shift-AltGr-[ ). It seems to be Ctrl-Option-Cmd-ç

Comment: Won't work for switching between split terminals, for that you need [@GabrielPetersson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62941912/1168116)

Comment: I am running VSC on Windows and hitting `Ctrl + PgUp` will just print out `^[[5;5~` characters in my Terminal windows, but thanks for the `Ctrl + Shift + \\` reminder, at least with that shortcut I can switch to the Terminal tabs view and move around with the Up and Down arrow keys and then hitting ENTER to activate the Terminal I want to use next.

Comment: There's also alt-up and alt-down if you have split terminals

Comment: Worked for me with no changes needed whatsoever, thanks.

Comment: If you don't have `PageUp` and `PageDown` keys on a condensed keyboard, try `fn+up` and `fn+down`

Answer (score 175):

Go to <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Keyboard Shortcuts</kbd> or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>.

Then click the icon in **upper right** corner, it opens `keybindings.json` file:

[image: Visual Guide]

Try adding the following two entries to this file:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+pagedown",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+pageup",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

> Note: On Mac change <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to <kbd>cmd</kbd>

Comment: Unfortunately, ```focusNext``` didn't work for me. Instead, ```focusNextPane``` worked like a charm.

Comment: `focusNextPane` works for split terminal, while `focusNext` works for different terminals in the dropdown list

Comment: `focusNext` --> `focusNextPane ` and `focusPrevious ` --> `focusPreviousPane` works for me to switch split terminal (left to right, right to left).

Comment: It's `pageDown` and `pageUp` (case-sensitive). Tested on Ubuntu 20.04, works great!

Answer (score 75):

Looking deeply I found it:

```
{
  "key": "shift+cmd+]",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext",
  "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

:)

Comment: where do u add this? `settings.json` ?

Comment: To add that go to File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts. Then Open 'keybindings.json'. Basically, the answer below by @Serhii is the right procedure

Comment: For windows user
"key": "shift+ctrl+]"
@baldam thanks. It worked as expected.

Answer (score 62):

`alt` + `up/down left/right arrows` to switch between splitted terminals.

If `alt` unfocuses your terminal and focuses the menu, add this to the *settings* file

```
// settings.json
"window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
"window.customMenuBarAltFocus": false
```

Comment: you might also need to press alt to gain focus

Comment: This solution did not work for me on unix. However @badran's did: `shift` + `cmd` + `]`

Comment: Nvm found the alt unfocus problem, added solution

Answer (score 37):

Improving on @Serhii Popov's answer

Use up and down instead of pageup and pagedown

Go to `File` → `Preferences` → `Keyboard Shortcuts` or just press Ctrl + k + Ctrl + s.

Then click the icon in upper right corner to open the keybindings.json file:

[image: Visual aid]

Then add the objects below to the array in the file:

```json
[
  ...
  {
    "key": "ctrl+down",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+up",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  }
  ...
]
```

Note: On Mac change `ctrl` to `cmd`

Comment: I'm not sure this counts as "improving" on their answer.  You copy-pasted it and changed one thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm on Ubuntu and it had  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPreviousPane", need to remove the Pane at the end.

Comment: Still valid. Thank you. I used alt instead since I remote into windows from a mac most of the day and ctrl+<any arrow> controls worksapces.

Answer (score 13):

On Windows 10 (not sure about Linux and Mac):

To switch between **split terminal windows** in Visual Studio Code use

> `Alt + Right arrow / Left arrow`

Comment: In Mac, it's CMD + Alt + Arrow Keys

Comment: you can also use Alt + `Up` / `Down` arrow :)

Answer (score 12):

On Windows

to switch terminal `ctrl` + `~`

to switch back to code editor `ctrl` + `1`

Comment: the most underrated anwser

Comment: For windows, this should be the exact answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I believe the answer you are looking for is `Cmd`+`Shift`+`[` (and `Cmd`+`Shift`+`]`)

Answer (score 8):

I've got `Ctrl+PageDown`/`Ctrl+PageUp` in my IDE Keyboard Shortcut settings, which I believe is the default as I didn't change them.

To figure out the shortcuts on your machine, go to *File>Preferences>Keyboard Shortcuts* and in the search box paste `workbench.action.terminal.focusNext` or `workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious`

This would only switch between terminal groups. So if 2 terminals were in the same group (that is there were split to display side-by-side), it wouldn't switch between those. To switch between terminals in the same group, use "Alt+LeftArrow" or "Alt+RightArrow".

*Credits to @Victory Ifebhor for the side-by-side case, clarified in the comments.*

Comment: This worked for me. I also found that it only switches between terminal groups. So if 2 terminals were in the same group (that is there were split to display side-by-side), it wouldn't switch between those.
To switch between terminals in the same group, use "Alt+LeftArrow" or "Alt+RightArrow".

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> can toggle(show/hide) the console.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my approach, which provides a consistent way of navigating between active terminals as well as jumping between the terminal and editor panes. You can try adding this to your `keybindings.json` directly but I would recommend you go through the keybinding UI (`cmd+K cmd+S` on a Mac) so you can review/manage conflicts etc.

With this I can use `ctrl+x <arrow direction>` to navigate to any visible editor or terminal. Once the cursor is in the terminal section you can use `ctrl+x ctrl+up` or `ctrl+x ctrl+down` to cycle through the active terminals (note that moving between on-screen split terminals is done with `ctrl+x left` or `ctrl+x right`).

`cmd-J` is still used to hide/show the terminal pane.

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+x right",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNextPane",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+x left",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPreviousPane",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+x ctrl+down",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+x ctrl+up",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+x up",
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateUp"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+x down",
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateDown"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+x left",
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateLeft",
        "when": "!terminalFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+x right",
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateRight",
        "when": "!terminalFocus"
    },
```

This is a work in progress as I'm trying to mimic my emacs behavior in VS Code, but some key elements are missing, like being able to navigate to a terminal buffer by name (without using a mouse/dropdown). Overall I'm pretty surprised by the poor editor group/pane navigation UX in an otherwise amazing product, but working on getting used to it.

Answer (score 3):

Pay attention to the the VS Code concept of **Group**, as that can trip you up when reading some of the answers here.

i.e there are different default shortcuts to switch between **terminals in the same group** (CMD+OPT+up/down) or between different **terminal groups** (SHIFT+CMD+[ / ])

Comment: Thanks for this. For me optimal flow from the editor to terminal is: 'ctrl + `', then 'cmd + opt + up/down', and then to get back to my code 'cmd + 1' (macOS)

Answer (score 3):

### Best personal settings to the keybindings.json file to solve it...

Steps:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>.
2. Then click the icon in upper right corner, it opens keybindings.json file
   [image]
3. Finally paste one of this codes:

**On windows** <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>

```json
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+win+down",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext",
        "when": "editorIsOpen && terminalHasBeenCreated && terminalIsOpen || terminalFocus && terminalIsOpen && terminalProcessSupported"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+win+up",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious",
        "when": "editorIsOpen && terminalHasBeenCreated && terminalIsOpen || terminalFocus && terminalIsOpen && terminalProcessSupported"
    }
]
```

**On Linux** <kbd>Meta</kbd>

```json
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+meta+down",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext",
        "when": "editorIsOpen && terminalHasBeenCreated && terminalIsOpen || terminalFocus && terminalIsOpen && terminalProcessSupported"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+meta+up",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious",
        "when": "editorIsOpen && terminalHasBeenCreated && terminalIsOpen || terminalFocus && terminalIsOpen && terminalProcessSupported"
    }
]
```

*This settings allows you to switch terminals without having the focus on terminal*

> Note: You can custom your keyboard shortcut as you want

Comment: You just made me realize that today, in 2023, on Linux, there are already shortcuts for these commands. Thanks! 
Ctrl + PgDown and Ctrl + PgUp

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else is so used to switching between tabs with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[0-9]</kbd> this mapping in your `keybindings.json` might useful:

```json
  {
    "key": "cmd+1",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusAtIndex1",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+2",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusAtIndex2",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+3",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusAtIndex3",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },
```

You can also extend the conditional in case you're using the terminal editor (to avoid switching when focused).

```json
  {
    "key": "cmd+1",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusAtIndex1",
    "when": "terminalFocus && !terminalEditorFocus"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

In current version of VSCode it is available like this. You can search this command in the Keyboard Shortcuts

workbench.action.terminal.focusNext

workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an easy custom keyboard shortcut in Vs Code for this

1. You can Ctrl-P and type Keyboard Shortcuts
2. search for "Terminal: switch active terminal"
3. set any key combination you want, mine is Ctrl+K since it wasn't used

Now you can switch to focus on the sidebar terminal without using your mouse but if you just want to switch to the main terminal Ctrl+J

[image: Using the Terminal Sidebar]

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to find the same shortcut, I found with VS code what helps is to know how the different UI components and actions are called.

In this case once "Keyboard Shortcuts" tab (where you can view and customize shortcuts) is open search for "prev terminal group" or "next terminal group".

We can see that VS Code has default shortcuts for:

- Terminal: Focus Previous Terminal Group
- Terminal: Focus Previous Terminal in Terminal Group

See results for my search:
[image]
I am not sure which one you are the most interested in but, try each and once you found the shortcut you were looking for: use it or customize it to your likings.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

For MacOs

> Move to left terminal - Cmd + Option + LeftArrow
> Move to right terminal - Cmd + Option + RightArrow

> Move to previous terminal - Ctrl+PageUp (macOS Cmd+Shift+])
> Move to next terminal - Ctrl+PageDown (macOS Cmd+shift+[)
> Focus terminal tabs view - Ctrl+Shift+\ (macOS Cmd+Shift+)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the existing bindings `` ctrl+` ``   to focus on the terminal panel when in the editor and `ctrl+shift+\` to focus on the terminal tabs panel and following custom keybinding `ctrl+shift+\` to focus back to the terminal panel when I am on the terminal tab panel, are just enough to skip completely mouse/touchpad while using the vscode.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+\\",
    "command": "terminal.focus",
    "when": "terminalHasBeenCreated && terminalTabsFocus && !terminalFocus || terminalProcessSupported && terminalTabsFocus && !terminalFocus"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS to navigate between splited terminals:

**⌥⌘←** Previous pane

**⌥⌘→** Next pane

[Here is the vs code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_groups-split-panes)