# VSCode Terminal Multiple Panes Switching Shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

As the title suggests, I'm trying to switch between terminal panes (not windows) withing the same terminal window. Obviously, clicking and mice aren't my thing.

All search results talk about either switching terminal windows or between terminal and code windows. I couldn't find anything specific to panes within a terminal window.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can rotate between terminal panes/panels:

```js
{
    "key": "ctrl+pagedown",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

As found in a previous question:
[How to switch between terminals in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440673/how-to-switch-between-terminals-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: As an addition, I find it nice to assign the same key shortcut to "Terminal:Focus Terminal". So you press the key once to get to the terminal, and then if you press it again it cycles tabs.