# How can I focus a VS Code terminal by profile name?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My question is quite similar to [How to switch between terminals in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48440673) except that I would like to be able to focus a specific terminal based on its name (as defined in the settings.json). Is this possible?

Understanding that there may be multiple simultaneous instances of the same terminal profile, it does not matter to me which of these instances is focused.

Comment: Looks like I might be able to use the Terminal namespace combined with the `name` property and `show` method. See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Terminal