# How do I get around the verified bug in Windows 1903 and launch the VSCode integrated terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10

I just did a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro version 1903 build 18362.116 and Visual Studio Code. Now the integrated terminal only launches externally.

Pressing `Ctrl` + `~` results in this.

[image: vscode non-integrated terminal]

What am I missing? How do I get it to open integrated again?

## EDIT

After working with VSCode team it is a verified bug. [See the Github issue here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73790). I posted the workaround as an answer here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch focus between editor and integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796887/switch-focus-between-editor-and-integrated-terminal-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate. Posted more details in the question and added a workaround as an answer. 

Comment: To save others like me some time: if you use Cmder, make sure it's not running. If it is running, toggling the Terminal in VS Code will switch to the Cmder window. If Cmder is not running, Ctrl + ` should toggle the integrated terminal.

Comment: @Arthur, I am still facing the issue. Have you figured out a solution yet?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

OK, worked through this one [in VSCode repo issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73790).

For now, until it's fixed, turn off ConPTY integration in the User Settings.

[image: vscode conpty setting]

Comment: In the same issue it's been suggested to instead turn off the "Use legacy console" setting in cmd.exe settings - this worked for me as well.

Comment: This results with `"terminal.integrated.windowsEnableConpty": false` in `settings.json`.

Comment: Had this issue today with latest build and this fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

The issue now says use legacy console. To change the setting open a cmd prompt. Right click the title to bring up properties.
[image: cmd properties]

Then Uncheck 'Use legacy console'
[image: Use legacy console]

Comment: This is the write option for open integreated terminal in vs code. When i uncheck the last checkbox the terminal open in vs code not in cmd windows separate from vs code.

Answer (score 3):

To change the integrated terminal on Windows, you just need to change the `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` line:

1. Open VS User Settings (Preferences > User Settings). This will open two side-by-side documents.
2. Check if `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows"` has value `"C:\\Bin\\Cmder\\Cmder.exe"` setting to the User Settings document on the right.
3. Remove this line.

`Ctrl` + `~` will now open integrated terminal of VSCode.

If the above solution doesn't work then can you try below values and check if it works for you:

// **Command Prompt**

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
```

// **PowerShell**

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
```

// **Git Bash**

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

// **Bash on Ubuntu (on Windows)**

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe"
```

From the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), use the View: Toggle Integrated Terminal command.

Try custom shortcut:

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+`",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ank. But it doesn't work. If I clear that setting (which had the path to cmd) vscode then opens powershell (the default Windows shell) in a separate window. 

Comment: I have updated the answer. Try it out and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Yeah... all those open the correct shell but they all open *externally*. The problem is they aren't being integrated into the integrated shell of vscode.

Comment: From the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), use the View: Toggle Integrated Terminal command.

Comment: No, sorry. That's the same as typing `ctrl` + `~`

Comment: Putting "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe" in settings.json worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem fixed. Found the solution from the VS Code support.

for error:

Terminal exits with code 3221225786 (or similar)#

"This can happen when you have legacy console mode enabled in conhost's properties. To change this, open cmd.exe from the start menu, right-click the title bar, go to Properties and under the Options tab, uncheck Use legacy console."

[image]

source: [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I changed the above settings to make it open internally
*might need to restart VS Code*