# I can't see integrated terminal option in view and only terminal is showing.How can i get integrated terminal on my visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When i press ctrl + ~ it opens cmd by default but i want integrated terminal window which now is not at all showing on my windows 10 machine . It only shows terminal option on view and no integrated terminal is shown at all..

here is the image:
https://filebin.net/iz1n9l30olw54aib/vs_code.PNG?t=f07bw7ub

Comment: this happens only on windows 10 update version 1903 and follow the link to resolve the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154957/how-do-i-get-around-the-verified-bug-in-windows-1903-and-launch-the-vscode-integ

Answer (score 1):

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to invoke the command dropdown. type in

**Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal**

the default hotkey for this on windows should be displayed next to the entry and might vary with your locale (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> on **en** layouts)

---

As mentioned in the comments by the **OP**:

## apparently this is a known bug

see [How do I get around the verified bug in Windows 1903 and launch the VSCode integrated terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154957/how-do-i-get-around-the-verified-bug-in-windows-1903-and-launch-the-vscode-integ)

Comment: tried...it by default opens up default cmd and not the integrated one :(

Comment: the thing is , in the view tab there is only a option as terminal and not integrated terminal

Comment: Finally found the issue..It a verified bug with windows update version 1903..   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154957/how-do-i-get-around-the-verified-bug-in-windows-1903-and-launch-the-vscode-integ