# Integrated terminal in visual studio code is opening externally and not internally

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I have reinstalled Visual Studio Code and for some reason, when I do the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> shortcut, instead of opening a terminal window inside VS Code, it's opening an external command window, which is very annoying.

Anyone knows what setting it is to get it back internally?

I tried File->Preferences->Settings->Terminal and then set the first option "Customizes what kind of terminal to launch." to integrated.

Is there any other setting I need to set?

Comment: You're not the only one, I just tried uninstalling and re-installing and it didn't fix this issue for me.

Comment: Turn off ConPTY integration in the Preferences/Settings. This is worked for me as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56267064/2462531

Answer (score 3):

Happened the same with me. It was because I was using Legacy Console. To disable that, open any of your terminal (cmd or powershell) and right click to go to properties.
`Properties` -> `Options` -> `Use Legacy console` (tick it off).

Answer (score 3):

Turn off ConPTY integration in the

> File->Preferences->Settings->conPTY->Uncheck it

This is worked for me as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56267064/2462531

Answer (score 0):

Found this:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/72033

Which is listed as a duplicate but someone was also kind enough to link to this:
[How do I get around the verified bug in Windows 1903 and launch the VSCode integrated terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154957/how-do-i-get-around-the-verified-bug-in-windows-1903-and-launch-the-vscode-integ)

Which has a workaround as an answer, yay!

Answer (score -1):

Here's some things you can check:

1. Make sure you've set `integrated` on both the **User** and the **Workspace** settings, because the **Workspace** settings can override the **User** settings.

   [image]
2. Make sure you are using the correct keyboard shortcut. VS Code actually has a shortcut for opening the system's native console, which will open an external window:

   [image]

   Make sure that your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> is actually the shortcut for *Create New Integrated Terminal*:

   [image]

Comment: sorry for the late reply @Gino but I tried all that and everything is how its set up in my application.  Really puzzled as to why since I have another machine, same settings, but acting differently