# how to stop VSCode terminal to open a new cmd window in each command?

Tags: visual-studio-code

On window 10 with vscode -v 1.51.1 terminal with cmd.

After writing the command and hitting the enter key... a new window is open and close...
so, if I'm trying to check --version the window is already close and i can't see results..
or if i having an error - i cant see it if the window is close... so for now: i use print screen..

how can i get the process output run on the same window... on the VSCode terminal?

[image]

Comment: its happened on most commands (--version is just an example)

Answer (score 0):

If am understanding your question you can try

```
code -v
```

Comment: yes if i am trying code -v its it's answering on the same window.. but if i try npm -v... it wouldn't... it open a new cmd window write the it's answer and close it.. very fast.. as soon as it finish the command

Comment: Try
`call npm -v`

Comment: call npm -v open in a new cmd window

Comment: Does your issue happen in other shells?

Comment: yes... it is.. in all commands i have used the issue persists, code -v is the only command that i get the answer on the same window.

Answer (score -2):

OMG

Turn off ConPTY integration in the

File->Preferences->Settings->conPTY->Uncheck it

[Integrated terminal in visual studio code is opening externally and not internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58246717/integrated-terminal-in-visual-studio-code-is-opening-externally-and-not-internal)

Comment: You do not need to write "OMG", just posting your answer is enough. To improve your answers, please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).