# Is there a way to switch tabs with CTRL+[NUMBER] instead of CTRL+TAB?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 and am frequently switching between several class files. The way I am having to do this is by pressing Ctrl+Tab (or Ctrl+Shift+Tab) repeatedly until I reach the desired tab.

It would be more convenient if there was a way to switch between tabs by pressing Ctrl+(tab's index) similar to how browser tabs are navigated. e.g. pressing Ctrl+1 opens the first/leftmost tab on your browser, Ctrl+2 opens the second one, etc.

Looking in Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard, there are commands that use View.NavigateBackward and View.NavigateForward (The Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab functionality) that can be re-mapped - however nothing for the functionality I described above.

There are threads solving this issue for Visual Studio Code, however (and I'm really surprised/must be really dumb that) there are no threads that I could find for just Visual Studio.

Threads for Visual Studio Code:

[Is there a quick change tabs function in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957302/is-there-a-quick-change-tabs-function-in-visual-studio-code/38962554)

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24753

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch to a specific tab with a keyboard shortcut with my [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension:

[image]

And you can additionally enable the **Show tab numbers** option to simplify usage of NavigateToTabXX commands:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So... After doing a more sensible search on StackOverflow instead of Google, I've found this thread;

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CTRL+Number+Visual+Studio

Which suggested to download a Visual Studio tool called "Hot Tabs". I have done so and it's working well for my purposes at the moment.

[Hot Tabs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotTabs)