# Is there a way to select a specific tab in Visual Studio with Keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: visual-studio

I'd love to be able to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc. to select open tabs in the editor by index. Does anyone know if this is possible in Visual Studio 2019?

Apparently this is possible in [Visual Studio *Code*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957302/is-there-a-quick-change-tabs-function-in-visual-studio-code), but I haven't been able to find anything for Visual Studio. The best I could find is an [extension that lets you select previous / next](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MackenzieZastrow.NavigateTabGroups), but not by index.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55886355/is-there-a-way-to-switch-tabs-with-ctrlnumber-instead-of-ctrltab

Comment: Looks like my post is a duplicate. ty sir. I do believe the Hot Tabs extension does the trick.

Comment: Actually, HotTabs only works for VS 2017, and the other option is a $100 plugin that completely reworks the tab system (I don't want that).