# how can I switch among tabs in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

my problem is how to switch tabs(scripts) in visual studio, like we can switch tabs in chrome by applying "Ctrl + 1,2,3" etc.

I tried a lot and I found backward and forward shortcuts in VS by applying "Ctrl+-" & "Ctrl + Shift+-"
but sometime it doesn't work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55886355/is-there-a-way-to-switch-tabs-with-ctrlnumber-instead-of-ctrltab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open Tools menu -> Options... -> Environment -> Keyboard you can find a list of available commands and what shortcuts are currently set. Many commands do not have a shortcut assigned.

I don't know about being able to jump to a specific tab such as your example, but I did find the following 2 commands:

Window.NextDocumentWindow (Default Shortcut: Ctrl + F6)

Window.PreviousDocumentWindow (Default Shortcut: Ctrl + Shift + F6)

That will at least allow you to cycle through tabs via the keyboard - tested it out.