# How can I switch between tabs only in the active editor group

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

In VS Code, whenever I'm in the split view (when I have multiple editor groups) and want to switch tabs with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, the tab switches fine until I reach the last tab on that active window (editor group). Then, instead of looping back to the first tab, it switches to the other split view window (editor group) instead.

I tried to see if there was any setting to disable this behavior but I couldn't find anything. Duplicating the other window instead of using split view works but isn't the best for my workflow.

Is there any setting to change the behavior so that it goes back to the first tab instead of switching to the other split window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I cannot reproduce this on Ubuntu.

For me, I can focus editor groups (what you are calling "splits") by number by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd><number></kbd>, or by directional navigation using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd><direction></kbd>, and open a quick cycle popup to cycle between editor tabs in the focused editor group by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>. I can also focus editor tabs in an editor group by index in that editor group using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd><index></kbd>.

For more similar info including default keybindings on other OSes, see [Is there a quick change tabs function in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38957302/11107541).

**What you are probably interested in** is the distinction between the following commands:

- `View: Open Next Editor` (bound by defaut on Windows and Linux to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>)
- `View: Open Next Editor in Group` (bound by defaut on Windows and Linux to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>)

The first is for cycling through editor tabs in all editor groups (which is the behaviour you don't want), and the second is for cycling through editor tabs in the currently focused editor group (which is the behaviour you do want, and which has no default keybinding).

If you don't like the default keybindings, just edit them to your liking (edit keybindings for the `workbench.action.nextEditorInGroup` command).

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I wanted! I'm using a Mac and changing the keybind to use the group version instead of the default version makes it so that only the active group will allow tab switching which is what I wanted.