# Is there any way to set a range of navigating tab as only in the activated tab group?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm in heavy use of navigating tabs through keyboard shortcut (cmd + shift + [ or ]).
And when I have multiple splited tab groups, it's uncomfortable to use shortcut because it navigates all workbench not just activated one tab group.
I want navigating work only in the activated tab group but I've not found any setting or way to make it.
Would be there any way to set this feature?
Thank you so much for the ones replies.

Comment: I find the wording here confusing and unclear. please try to clarify what you're looking for. are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/q/74662198/11107541 ?